# FFmpeg extract frames from video

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg

I am currently using FFmpeg in Android with this [lib](https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java). I am trying to extract 1 frame each second from a video. My current command is:

```
final String cmd[] = {"-i" + videoPath +  "-vf fps=1" +  mediaStorageDir.getAbsolutePath() + "a.png"};
```

Now i understand if this code were right the image would keep being overlapped because every image is called a.png. This is not the problem right now this code was for testing but I cant even get the command to work.

this is the error

> Error splitting the argument list: Option not found

Any help is much appreciated. P.S i used [this documentation](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20thumbnail%20image%20every%20X%20seconds%20of%20the%20video) to find the command

Comment: You will need a %d in your output png filename and mind the spaces in your str adding.

Answer (score 0):

Use Like Below code

```
 File dest = new File(dir, filePrefix + "%03d" + fileExtn);


final String cmd[] = {"-i" + videoPath +  "-vf fps=1" +  mediaStorageDir.getAbsolutePath() + dest.getAbsolutePath()};
```